# Number of computations for multiplication

Tags: complexity-theory, multiplication

I just read [Marvin Minskys' "Form and Content in Computer Science"](https://web.media.mit.edu/~minsky/papers/TuringLecture/TuringLecture.html) and found myself confused with the following paragraph:

> A startling discovery was made about multiplication itself in the
>   thesis of S.A. Cook [3], which uses a result of A.L. Toom, as
>   discussed in Knuth [4]. Consider the ordinary algorithm for
>   multiplying decimal numbers: for two n-digit numbers this employs
>   n-squared one-digit products. It is usually supposed that this is
>   minimal. But suppose we write the numbers in two halves, so that the
>   product is N = (#A+B)(#C+D), where # stands for multiplying by 10 subscript{n/2}.
>   (The left-shift operation is considered to have negligible cost.) Then
>   one can verify that
>
> N = ##AC + BD + #(A+B)(C+D) - #(AC+BD).
>
> This involves only three half-length multiplications, instead of the
>   four that one might suppose were needed. For large n, the reduction
>   can obviously be reapplied over and over to the smaller numbers. The
>   price is a growing number of additions. By compounding this and other
>   ideas, Cook showed that for any e and large enough n, multiplication
>   requires less than n*(1-e) products, instead of the expected
>   n-squared.

I got stuck when I read `stands for multiplying by 10 ...` because I didn't understand what the subscript in this example means. I tried to find it out by googling about the complexity of multiplication and stuff like that, but couldn't find the answer.

Can you point me in the right direction here? I guess that this exact part is essential for understanding the formula in the middle. I would like to find out how this computation would resolve a multiplication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be "10 superscript{n/2}" meaning $10^{n/2}$. For example, if $n=4$, then "6#2" would represent $6\cdot10^2=600$. All he's doing is shifting a decimal number to the left.

Answer (score 4):

From context it's just exponentiation.  I don't know why it's written with a subscript instead of a superscript, but with older papers you sometimes had a professional typesetter who might not have understood the material.  (Of course nowadays typically do their own typesetting.)